# Restart rails server on git commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I'm setting up a shared development server for a Ruby on Rails project.

Is there a good way to set it up to restart, or reload the code every time someone pushes a commit to the master branch (for example)? I don't care about setting up gems etc every time, à la Heroku - I just want to run the new code.

If there are any problems, I can go in and restart the server manually - I just don't want to do it every time.

Comment: I don't have much experience with them, but you could check out native [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 3):

[The post-receive hook runs after the entire process is completed and can be used to update other services or notify users.](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html#Server-Side-Hooks)

In the post-receive hook, you'll most likely need to grep for the Ruby PID, kill that process and then restart the Rails server.

Answer (score 3):

[Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is what you're looking for.

Using these, you can run custom commands based on certain conditions.

Create a file named `post-commit` under your `.git/hooks` folder like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec rake deploy
```

and in your Rakefile,

```
task :deploy do
  pid = IO.open("ps").grep(/script\/rails/) { |x| x.split(" ").first }.first
  sh "kill -9 #{pid}"
  sh "rails s"
end
```

Comment: There's gotta be a cleaner way to get the pid of the server process. Do check it. This example will have unexpected consequences if used when multiple instances of `rails s` are running on your machine.